# How to run Django api's asynchronously

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a long-running API in Django.
When this long-running API is invoked by user1, the other APIs get blocked for user1 until that long-running API call gets resolved. But at the same time for other users, those APIs work well.

```
class CreateOrderAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        # Creates order
        # Some third-party services are invoked (Takes so long)
        return Response(order_data, status=201)
```

Example

Now, when the above API is called by user1, the other API calls get blocked for user1 until the long-running call is completed. However, the other users can invoke the APIs at the same time.

I don't want to go with the celery/redis approach for my long-running tasks for now.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: For long running tasks, async will not solve the problem. You need to implement a task queue system. Celery works will with Django https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize Python's built-in `asyncio` library. You can create an asynchronous function to handle the long-running task and use `asyncio.run()` to execute it asynchronously within your API view.

#### EXAMPLE

```
import asyncio
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class CreateOrderAPIView(APIView):

    async def create_order_async(self, request):
        # Simulate long-running task
        await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Example: Simulate a task that takes 5 seconds

        # Generate order data
        order_data = {"order_id": 123, "status": "created"}

        return order_data

    async def post(self, request):
        # Execute the long-running task asynchronously
        order_data = await self.create_order_async(request)

        return Response(order_data, status=201)
```